# Visual Studio 2017 using EF Core change local database default location for mdf file before/after migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

I may need help with the title of my question. So here is more detail.

In VS2015 I when creating a database using code first migrations, After completing my first migration I was able to view the database in VS by going to the App_Data folder and clicking on the MDF file. It would then open in Server Explorer.

However, in VS2017 I no longer have an App_Data folder and when I did my first migration it took a bit of work to find out where my MDF file was located.

If you don't know here are the steps I used to locate it:

After doing the add-migration and update-database.

Go to View->SQL Server Object Explorer

Under SQL Server look for you (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB->Databases->name of your databases should show in your appsettings.json connection string. Probably starts with aspnet-[db name]-[bunch of numbers and letters]

I right clicked on this database and went to properties.
Under "Current Connection Parameters" is the path to the MDF file.

The current location is "C:/user/username"

So my question is how do I set this to a different default location? I would like my MDF files to show in the Data folder or something similar that is in my project folder.

If this question has been asked. I apologize I tried rewording my question about 20 times to figure out if someone already asked it. I will quickly remove this question if it has already been asked in a way that is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: I will also add that you can move an existing databases mdf file to the new location use server explorer to connect and then copy the connection string from server explorer into your appsettings.json and refresh. Everything should show up in the new location. I accepted Austins as the answer because he also explained how to do a new connection in your chosen location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so for Entity Framework Core, it is a bit more involved. You can open your db in `SQL Server Object Explorer` in Visual Studio (or in Sql Management Studio) and create your database where you want it using a SQL query.

```
create database test on (name='test', filename='c:\Projects\test.mdf');
```

And then reference it using (LocalDb) the way you normally would in the connection string:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

And then this test runs correctly

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

            var context = new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}
```

So you're still using the same server, but you're placing the database in the folder you want.

In action:
[image]

Comment: I knew I was missing something. I'm using EF core. Do you know how to do this in EF Core?

Comment: Thanks when I get a chance to try this I will let you know if it worked and mark as answered if everything works out which I'm sure it will :-).

Comment: The solution is correct. Still wants to point out that it has nothing to do with EF Core. When you create a new database in SqlServer and do not specify the file, the MDF files are created in the default location set for the given server. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-change-the-default-locations-for-data-and-log-files EF just calls the server to create file. With solution above you will explicitly specify location of the file and tell server where it is. EF just talks to server instance and not interact with the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **AttachDbFileName** in your connection string like :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString: @"data source=.;AttachDbFileName=d:\data\yourDBname.mdf ;initial catalog=yourDBname;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
```