# How to create database in another location instead of default lactation c:\Users\USER in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to create database in a folder in my project, but by default the database is created in C:\Users\USER.

This is my appsetting.json :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMusicStoreContext": 
      "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMusicStoreContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  }
```

How to change database location to another folder in my computer.  I use asp.net core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Do you think this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150238/localdb-change-sql-server-default-location

Comment: no in asp.net core I do not have access web.config

Comment: You're right, this might be more of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709499/visual-studio-2017-using-ef-core-change-local-database-default-location-for-mdf

Comment: This is the solution for Entity Framework (EF) Core,but i use asp.net core

Comment: I think asp.net core uses EF under the hood.Can you still try the commands form my second link? After you create a DB and update the connection string properly in your `appsetting.json` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change ConnectionStrings with AttachDBFileName:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMusicStoreContext":
    //"Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMusicStoreContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFilename=[DataDirectory]\\App_Data\\MvcMusicStoreContext.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

  }
```

and in ConfigureServices in startup:

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 

  services.AddDbContext<MvcMusicStoreContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMusicStoreContext")
                  .Replace("[DataDirectory]",path)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the above solution did not work in VS2019 (16.8.4) in my Razor project (Core 3.1):

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\WebApplication1\App_Data\WebApp1db.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

The solution was to add `Initial Catalog=MyNotAutoNamedDb;` to `appsetting.json` project file. Before that, you should also create the `App_Data` directory specified in the path.

`appsettings.json`

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;AttachDBFilename=[DataDirectory]\\App_Data\\WebApp1db.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyNotAutoNamedDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
```

`Startup.cs`

```
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
        .Replace("[DataDirectory]", path)));
```

Please also don't forget to add using `System.IO;` to your `Startup.cs` file.
I tested the solution creating model, adding migration and updating database using EF, works without problems with the database file in the project structure.